# Average revenue from price-demand function?

Tags: calculus

I came across a calculus question in which I don't even understand what the question is asking. It went something like this:

The price-demand equation is $p(x)=100-15x$. What is the average revenue at $x=5$?

How can you have the average of something at a single point? Do we just do $p(5)=25$ so $R=px=25(5)=125$?

Does average mean revenue per unit in which case we'd divide the $125$ by $5$? If so, I don't see how this is a calculus question. Thanks!

Comment: Even before your questions, what is $x$?  Usually I see a price-demand equation expressed as $q$ (quantity) as a function of $p$ (price).  You seem to be taking $x$ to be quantity.  After that, I agree with you we need a definition of average revenue.  We usually assume all units are sold at the same price, so your approach makes sense to me.  Maybe they are assuming you sell the first unit at the price where the quantity is $1$, the second at the price where the quantity is $2$ and so on.  It will still be an arithmetic average with no calculus required.

Comment: In this case, $x$ represented quantity, yes. I believe the poster of the answer is dead on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in consumer/producer theory, "average" metrics are per-unit, i.e., divided by quantity demanded/supplied.

So, the demand curve *is* the average revenue curve. In the absence of price discrimination, at any fixed quantity $x$, the average revenue is simply

$$AR(x) = \frac{R(x)}{x} = \frac{p(x)*x}{x} = p(x) .$$

There's no calculus involved here, the answer is just $p(5) = 25$.